# GLM: Sigmoid link with MSE for linear regression?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, mse, sigmoid-curve

I have a relatively simple regression problem where I wanted to model y given x. X is continuous and is bounded [0,inf); y is bounded (0,1).

My question is, is it appropriate for me to insert a sigmoid link function into my linear regression model?

Predicted values of y should never exceed 1 or go short of 0. The sigmoid function should enforce this.

However, the loss function with be mean squared error.

I think that this is an acceptable GLM, however, I’d like community consensus

Answer (score 1):

It’s no longer a linear model, but it’s fine to use a nonlinear link function with mean squared error loss. Mean squared error loss corresponds to maximum likelihood estimation of a Gaussian likelihood, and the link function does not change that. I have not heard of the nonlinear link function being sigmoid, but I have heard of using a $\log$ link with a Gaussian likelihood (so mean squared error as the loss).

I have my doubts that you really want a Gaussian conditional distribution if you want your $\hat y$ bounded between $0$ and $1$, but that is a separate matter.

Comment: I see. To make things more complicated, I’ll be using a Bayesian paradigm, so the likelihood is a bit ambiguous here. Perhaps Gaussian is the way to go, as would be for linear regression.